# Error on deploy Firebase cloud function Each then() should return a value or throw

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Any suggestions on what is wrong here? The code is from google this tutorial from Google https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/guard-your-web-content-from-abuse-with.html

Getting this error when trying to deploy on Firebase.

> error Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return

and here is the code:

```
//recaptcha
exports.checkRecaptcha = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const response = req.query.response;
    console.log("recaptcha response", response);
    rp({
        uri: 'https://recaptcha.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
        method: 'POST',
        formData: {
            secret: 'my_secret_key',
            response: response
        },
        json: true
    }).then(result => {
        console.log("recaptcha result", result);
        if (result.success) {
            res.send("You're good to go, human.");
        }
        else {
            res.send("Recaptcha verification failed. Are you a robot?");
        }
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log("Recaptcha request failure", reason);
        res.send("Recaptcha request failed.");
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Inside `then()` , try changing `res.send(...` to `return res.send(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that every `.then()` method must return something.

If you don't care about the return value, you could `return null;` after your entire `else` block.

Here, you can do this:

```
if (result.success) {
    return res.send("You're good to go, human.");
}
return res.send("Recaptcha verification failed. Are you a robot?");
```

*(The `else` is not needed because `return` stops the execution of the method, and thus won't execute the lines after)*